# Mock rest api & fake domain

Tags: javascript, mocking, automated-tests, wiremock

I was trying to create a basic mock server, that allows some simple JSON responses for REST calls. I wanted everything to run on node, as this is the current dev environment for the team, so I came up with apimocker, jswiremock, etc. which all work like a charm on localhost. So good, so far.

What I really need now is to have everything running on a fake domain on my localhost --> just like fiddler/charles does redirect domain calls to the correspondant localhost resource. How can I manage to have that? - would be perfect to have that in the node world, too.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following process:

- Setup a hosts file to map the hostname to localhost
- Use a [hosts module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hostile) for programmatic access to the hosts file
- Use a [proxy module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-ssl-proxy) to emulate SSL

**References**

- [Dockerizing a Node.js web app | Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/)
- [DNS | Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html)
- [TLS (SSL) | Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html)